# React Testing Library and Vitest - element is visible before updating state

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, vitest

As a newbie, I am trying to learn to write some tests.

I built a simple component with an input, and a button to display the text input after clicking on the button.
The span is initially hidden, and it changes to visible after clicking on the button

This is the component

```
function Contact() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleSendContactRequest = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShow(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      <span
        data-testid="message"
        style={{ visibility: show ? "visible" : "hidden" }}
      >
        {name} , check your inbox
      </span>
      <form action="">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="name"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={handleSendContactRequest}>Send contact request</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default Contact;
```

I created a test to check that the span is initially hidden, that it passes, and a second to check the whole flow.

```
//this test passes. span is not visible
test("span should not be visiblet", () => {
  render(<Contact />);

  const span = screen.getByTestId("message");
  expect(span).not.toBeVisible();
});

test("should display name in the span after clicking the button", () => {
 render(<Contact />);

  const nameInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText("name");
  fireEvent.change(nameInput, { target: { value: "tom" } });

  const sendButton = screen.getByText("Send contact request");

  const hiddenSpan = screen.queryByText(
    "tom , check your account tom@test.com"
  );
  expect(hiddenSpan).toBeNull(); // do not pass. spann is visible after fireEvent.change()

  fireEvent.click(sendButton);

  const spanElement = screen.getByText("tom , check your inbox");

  expect(spanElement).toBeVisible();


});
```

I am writting the test correctly?
I do not understand why `span` has content after the `fireEvent.change()` when the previous test passed.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking for the wrong property. Since I just show and hide the element, methods like `.findByText()`  `.queryByText` can still access to the value of the element, and methods like `.toBeInTheDocument()` or `.toBe()` will have access to the `innerHTML` and `textContent` of the element.

Just to check for `.toBeVisible()` seems to work fine.
I modified the test :

```
test("should span be visible and contain a name value after clicking button", () => {
  render(<Contact />);
  const span = screen.getByTestId("message");
  expect(span).not.toBeVisible();
  const nameInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText("name");
  const nameInputValue = "Tom";
  const sendButton = screen.getByRole("button");

  fireEvent.change(nameInput, { target: { value: nameInputValue } });
  fireEvent.click(sendButton);


  expect(span).toBeVisible();
  
  expect(span.innerHTML).toBe(
    `${nameInputValue} , check your inbox`
  );
});
```

This test will pass, and if I comment out `fireEvent.click(sendButton);`, it won't.